# exec: "make": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown - Docker and kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Trying to build a website using docker, kubernetes and helm. Couldn't find this exact issue, but from what I've gathered from similar issues is that "make" isn't a command on windows, so because of this, I believe, it produces this error. I've tried installing `make` in the Dockerfile and using `CMD ["make", "start-server"]`. On a docker test run (using `docker build -t test .` and `docker run test`) I am able to "start" the development server - but when I deploy to Kubernetes it produces the error in question I've been trying to fix.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9.12-slim as production

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /app/

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    make \
    bash \
    gcc \
    libffi-dev \
    musl-dev \
    openssl \
    postgresql \
    libpq-dev

COPY requirements/prod.txt ./requirements/prod.txt
RUN pip install -r ./requirements/prod.txt

COPY manage.py ./manage.py
COPY setup.cfg ./setup.cfg
COPY Personal_Website ./Personal_Website
COPY Makefile ./Makefile

EXPOSE 8000

COPY requirements/dev.txt ./requirements/dev.txt
RUN pip install -r ./requirements/dev.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["make", "start-server"]
```

I am pulling an image from my docker hub repository.
Part of my deployment.yaml:

```
containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          securityContext:
            {{- toYaml .Values.securityContext | nindent 12 }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          command: ["make", "start-server"]
. . .
```

And my Error Stack:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason          Age                       From     Message
  ----     ------          ----                      ----     -------
  Warning  BackOff         3d11h (x1752 over 3d17h)  kubelet  Back-off restarting failed container
  Normal   SandboxChanged  89s                       kubelet  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Normal   Pulled          37s (x3 over 87s)         kubelet  Container image "dockerid/personal-website:v0.0.11" already present on machine
  Normal   Created         37s (x3 over 86s)         kubelet  Created container django-website
  Warning  Failed          37s (x3 over 86s)         kubelet  Error: failed to start container "django-website": Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "make": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
  Warning  BackOff         13s (x11 over 86s)        kubelet  Back-off restarting failed container
```

If anything else is needed, let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have the logs in plain-text format, instead of an image file?  That will be much easier to read and search for.  What steps are you going through in between creating the Dockerfile and installing the Helm chart; are you sure the image you're running in the cluster matches the one you've built locally?  Can you `docker run` the container without Kubernetes?

Comment: @DavidMaze I am able to use docker run without Kubernetes. I'll move into plain text format in just a second. In terms of steps,  I am using `docker push tag=...` with a specific tag I set. Then I am using `helm upgrade --install personal-website ./helm/django-website`, then using `kubectl` to check my pod.

Comment: Are you changing the tag version each time you push your image?

Comment: @jordanm Yes, I am.

Comment: @DavidMaze Updated the post.

Comment: The other thing that comes to mind: are you potentially building the image on one architecture (an ARM-based M1 Mac, for example) but pushing to a Kubernetes cluster with another architecture (x86-based cloud servers)?  You shouldn't need the `command:` override in the Helm chart, but I also wouldn't expect deleting it to make a difference for this error.

Comment: @DavidMaze The image uses amd64 as its architecture. Can't seem to find the info on the Kubernetes cluster architecture.

Comment: @DavidMaze Do you have any other ideas as to what it could be? I'm still struggling to find solutions.

Comment: @jordanm Do you have any ideas as to what else could be the problem?

Comment: Please someone help... I'm having no luck in any google searches.